# Jenkins - Help needed to copy a local code file to Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, copy, workspace

New to Jenkins. I need help to copy a local Python script file to Jenkins workspace.
Can someone guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copy <src file> <destination directory>` to copy files.
Below will copy all python files into Workspace directory

```
bat  "copy /Y C:\\MyProject\\*.py ${Workspace}\\"
```

Comment: Should I give this in my Jenkins Build step ? This is a one time copy of file, there is going to be no change in code.

Comment: @user16120973 yes or you can also use ``dir(<Path where script exsist>){}``, so you dont need to copy any files then

Comment: Nope, its not working for me. Getting this error.                C:\Users\PycharmProjects\TestProject\JenkinsPythonscript.py ${Workspace}\\" 
14:25:01 'bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
14:25:01 operable program or batch file.
14:25:01 
14:25:01 c:\jenkins\workspace\Dev\gNS\TestAutomation\Cert1_Regression>exit 9009 
14:25:01 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Comment: @user16120973 you need to put ``\\`` instead of ``\`` and bat with ``"`` . did you run the command with exact same way.

Comment: I have this script file on my local machine. Will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using powershell like this..

```
     withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'settings-xml', variable: 'FILE')]) {
        echo "^^^^^ Copying file to ${env.WORKSPACE}\\src\\main\\resources ^^^^^^"
        bat 'powershell Copy-Item %FILE% -Destination .\\src\\main\\resources'
        ...
     }
```